# save forms of relationed tables symfony2 using entityType class

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need help again with symfony2. I have 2 clases `Productos` and `Categoria`, when I displayed in my view list of `Productos` en the field `categoriaId` the value is a integer... i used entityType field to show `NombreCategoria` of my class `Categoria`... but when i save the form of `Productos`, the value of my `categoriaId` field is 0 in my BD... i dont know where is the problem.. i want save the `id` in my class `Producto`..
this is my view

```
<form role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{path('producto_new')}}">
    <table class="record_properties">
        {{form(form)}}
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is my Entity

```
namespace ebay\bdBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class producto{
    private $id;
    private $nombre;
    private $categoriaId;
    private $descripcion;
    private $color;
    private $precio;
    private $imag;
    private $total;
    private $flag;

    /**
     * Get id
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    { return $this->id; }

    /**
     * Set nombre
     * @param string $nombre
     * @return producto
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre){
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get nombre
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNombre()
    { return $this->nombre; }

    /**
     * Set categoriaId
     * @param integer $categoriaId
     * @return producto
     */
    public function setCategoriaId($categoriaId){
        $this->categoriaId = $categoriaId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get categoriaId
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCategoriaId()
    { return $this->categoriaId; }

    /**
     * Set descripcion
     * @param string $descripcion
     * @return producto
     */
    public function setDescripcion($descripcion){
        $this->descripcion = $descripcion;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descripcion
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescripcion()
    { return $this->descripcion; }

    /**
     * Set color
     * @param string $color
     * @return producto
     */
    public function setColor($color){
        $this->color = $color;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get color
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getColor()
    { return $this->color; }

    /**
     * Set precio
     * @param integer $precio
     * @return producto
     */
    public function setPrecio($precio){
        $this->precio = $precio;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get precio
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPrecio()
    { return $this->precio; }

    /**
     * Set envio
     * @param string $imag
     * @return producto
     */
    public function setImag($imag){
        $this->imag = $imag;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imag
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImag()
    { return $this->imag; }

    /**
     * Set total
     * @param integer $total
     * @return producto
     */
    public function setTotal($total){
        $this->total = $total;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTotal()
    { return $this->total; }

    /**
     * Set flag
     * @param boolean $flag
     * @return producto
     */
    public function setFlag($flag){
        $this->flag = $flag;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get flag
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getFlag()
    { return $this->flag; }
}
```

This is my Form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
  $builder
        ->add('nombre','text', array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:10px')))
        ->add('categoriaId','entity', array('class'=>'bdBundle:categoria','label'=>'descripcion', 'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:10px'),'data' => '$id'))
        ->add('descripcion','text', array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:10px')))
        ->add('color','text', array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:10px')))
        ->add('precio','text', array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:10px')))
        ->add('imag','file', array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:10px'),'label'=>'Imagen', 'data_class'=>null))
        ->add('total','text', array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:10px')))
        ->add('flag','choice', array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:10px'),'choices'=>array('1'=>'Vigente'),'required'=>true))
  ;
}
```

and This is my Controller

```
public function newAction(Request $request){
    $entity = new Producto();
    $form = $this->createForm(new productoType, $entity);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $image = $entity->getImag();

        if(($image instanceof UploadedFile) && ($image->getError() == '0')){
            $originalName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $name_array = explode('.',$originalName);
            $file_type = $name_array[sizeof($name_array) - 1];
            $valid_filetypes = array('jpg','jpeg','png');
            if(in_array(strtolower($file_type), $valid_filetypes)){
                $document = new Document();
                $document->setFile($image);

                $document->setSubDirectory('productos');
                $document->processFile();

                $entity->setImag($image->getBasename());

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $em->persist($entity);
                $em->flush();

                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('mensaje',
                        'Se inserto la imagen correctamente');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('producto'));
            }else{
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('mensaje',
                        'La extension del archivo no es la correcta');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('producto_new'));
            } 
        }else{
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('mensaje',
                    'No ingreso el archivo o se produjo un error inesperado');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('producto_new'));
        }   
    }

    return $this->render('bdBundle:producto:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form-> createView(),));
}
```

Anyone can help me please..

i forget show my `Categoria` entity...

```
namespace ebay\bdBundle\Entity;
```

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * categoria
 */
class categoria
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $descripcion;

/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $flag;

public function __toString()
{
  return $this->getDescripcion();
} 


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set descripcion
 *
 * @param string $descripcion
 * @return categoria
 */
public function setDescripcion($descripcion)
{
    $this->descripcion = $descripcion;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get descripcion
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescripcion()
{
    return $this->descripcion;
}

/**
 * Set flag
 *
 * @param boolean $flag
 * @return categoria
 */
public function setFlag($flag)
{
    $this->flag = $flag;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get flag
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getFlag()
{
    return $this->flag;
}
```

}

Comment: You have no mapping between your two entities ?? (ManyToOne, ManyToMany? ...). Where's the code of your Categoria entity ?

Comment: If you are using the entity form type the form component calls the setCategoriaId of Productos with the entity object (Categoria) - *not* the id of that entity. So with that form configuration for categoriaId your private $categoriaId would be an object after submit, not an integer.
Perhaps your database layer is casting the object after that to the value "0"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

efectly the problem was a entity relations oneToMany and manyToOne...

```
manyToOne:
    proveedor:
        targetEntity: Proveedor
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            proveedor_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
    producto:
        targetEntity: Producto
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            producto_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

with that all its ok... thanks all guys..